# When do you flip a coin for conditions

Tags: pokemon

I understand that you flip a coin to check if a pokemon wakes up. Assume that my son puts my active Pokémon to sleep (he has a Litwick which does this very easily). At the end of his turn do I get to check if the Pokémon wakes up?

[image: Litwick GRI]

If yes but I get unlucky, or if not: since I can't retire a sleeping Pokémon I am basically stuck during my turn unless I have some special effect card that allows for switch, right? Now at the end of my turn do I get to flip at least?

Basically, who gets to flip at the end of whose turn? The rules online are not detailed enough...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Rulebook](https://assets.pokemon.com//assets/cms2/pdf/trading-card-game/rulebook/sm9_rulebook_en.pdf), page 15:

> **Asleep**
> Turn the Pokémon counterclockwise to show that it is Asleep.
>
> If a Pokémon is Asleep, it cannot attack or retreat. Between turns, flip a coin. If you flip heads, the Pokémon wakes up (turn the card right-side up), but if you flip tails, it stays Asleep.

Flipping for sleep occurs *between turns*. On the same page, there is a brief description of what *between turns* means:

> Before the game continues to the next player, take care of Special Conditions in this order:
>
> 1. POISONED     2. BURNED     3. ASLEEP     4. PARALYZED
>
> Then, apply the effects of any Abilities (or anything else that a card states must happen between turns). After *both players* have done these things, check to see if any affected Pokémon were Knocked Out. Then, start the next player’s turn!

(emphasis mine)

It doesn't matter whose Pokémon is asleep, it doesn't matter whose turn is next.

In your example, yes, you get to flip before your round starts (that means 50% probability that you would be stuck with sleeping Pokémon) and after your turn ends, you get to flip again.

Comment: Ok I wasn't sure if that only applied to the player who had just completed its turn. I have played like that since it seemed to me the most sensible interpretation but I wanted to be sure because I don't want to "unknowingly cheat" with my kid, who owns these "put opponents to sleep" cards.

Comment: By the way now that you pointed it out, I have found the "both players" reference in the rulebook. I will mark the answer as accepted!